# How to batch rename

Tags: batch, batch-rename

I want to batch rename files

I have a folder and in that folder there are files that I want to change name to 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc..

Thank you for your time

Comment: Could you be a little more explicit about what the names currently are and what you want them to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code for that purpose,

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
dir=/path/to/folder
j=1
for i in $dir/*
do
    mv "$i" "$dir/$j"
    let j=j+1
done
```

Save it as say `batch_rename.sh`, give it execution permission as,

```
chmod +x /path/to/batch_rename.sh
```

execute it as,

```
./batch_rename.sh
```